# Connecting Python to MySQL using an encrypted option file

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I used `mysql_config_editor` to create a `.mylogin.cnf` file with a password. I know it worked correctly because I can use it to connect through both the command line utility `mysql` and the R package `RMySQL` without a problem.

However, when trying to connect using Mysql-Connector/Python:

```
# using mysql-connector-python-rf
import os
import mysql.connector
con = mysql.connector.connect(option_files=os.path.expanduser('~/.mylogin.cnf'))
```

or with PyMySQL:

```
# using pymysql
import os
import pymysql
con = pymysql.connect(option_files=os.path.expanduser('~/.mylogin.cnf'))
```

I get the same error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-d17e56ef7010> in <module>()
----> 1 con = mysql.connector.connect(option_files=os.path.expanduser('~/.mylogin.cnf'))

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py in connect(*args, **kwargs)
    140     # Option files
    141     if 'option_files' in kwargs:
--> 142         new_config = read_option_files(**kwargs)
    143         return connect(**new_config)
    144 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/optionfiles.py in read_option_files(**config)
     66             config['option_files'] = [config['option_files']]
     67         option_parser = MySQLOptionsParser(list(config['option_files']),
---> 68                                            keep_dashes=False)
     69         del config['option_files']
     70 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/optionfiles.py in __init__(self, files, keep_dashes)
    162             self.files = files
    163 
--> 164         self._parse_options(list(self.files))
    165         self._sections = self.get_groups_as_dict()
    166 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/optionfiles.py in _parse_options(self, files)
    193                                      "than once in the list".format(file_))
    194                 with open(file_, 'r') as op_file:
--> 195                     for line in op_file.readlines():
    196                         if line.startswith('!includedir'):
    197                             _, dir_path = line.split(None, 1)

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/encodings/ascii.py in decode(self, input, final)
     24 class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
     25     def decode(self, input, final=False):
---> 26         return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
     27 
     28 class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Skimming over the source code, it looks like these are trying to read the files in cleartext. However, `mysql_config_editor` encrypts the login file it generates. Both modules work fine when entering the password manually in the code.

How can I connect to Python using one of these generated config files? I'm using Python 3, so MySQLdb isn't an option.

update: for now, I'm using [RPy2](http://rpy2.readthedocs.org/) to run queries in R and pipe the results back into Python. The code is a little ugly but the workflow isn't so bad.

Comment: Likely you already know this, but the cleartext ~/.my.cnf option file will work with Mysql-Connector/Python > 2.0.

Comment: @Ian yup, the whole point is _not_ to use cleartext. but i switched over to it anyway out of frustration...

Comment: True, [but.](http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2012/08/16/understanding-mysql_config_editors-security-aspects/)

Comment: @Ian in my understanding the encryption used is pretty weak. so if someone really wanted to get at my stuff it wouldn't be much of an obstacle.

Comment: The `.mylogin.cnf` file is not really encrypted anyway, since it contains the key to decrypt it. It's just obfuscated. There are various scripts online to extract the plain text, among which [myloginpath.py](https://github.com/PyMySQL/myloginpath/blob/master/myloginpath.py) from the module in exic's answer. Or even just the command `my_print_defaults -s root`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pip install myloginpath`](https://github.com/PyMySQL/myloginpath) worked for me, then:

```
import myloginpath
import pymysql
conf = myloginpath.parse('client')
db = pymysql.connect(**conf, host='mydbhost', db='whatever')
```

Comment: Nice find, I don't think this existed back then.

Comment: True, it probably didn't :-)